# For Each Item in a Table with a Property Like This, Do this in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, phpmyadmin

I have a database with Collumns of 'id' 'assetTag' 'wsId'
 The 'wsId' collumn is not unique, where there are many 'assetTag' with the same 'wsId'

What I want to do is, for every row with a certain 'wsId' like ws-101, I want to echo something in php. How do I go about doing that? I'm confused about the use of foreach in php so I'm reluctant to use that.

Here's some code I wrote:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $pc = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "\r\n".'<div id="popup" title="'.$pc['id'].'" >';
    echo "\r\n\t".'<div id="accordion">';

    echo "\r\n\t\t".'<h3>General Information</h3>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t".'<div>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'<table>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."Computer Name";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="computerName" value="'.$pc['id'].'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."Position";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="computerName" value="'.$pc['position'].'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."MAC Address";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="macAddress" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."PORT NUMBER";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="portNumber" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."Notes";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="notes" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'</table>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t".'</div>';   //for box

    echo "\r\n\t\t".'<h3>HARDWARE</h3>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t".'<div>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'<table>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."ASSET CODE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="assetCode" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."TYPE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="assetType" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."ASSET NAME";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="assetName" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."SERIAL NUMBER";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="serialNumber" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."YEAR OF PURCHASE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="yearOfPurchase" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."CAPITALIZATION DATE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="capitalizationDate" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."LOCATION";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="location" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."CUSTODIAN NAME";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="custodianName" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'</table>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t".'</div>';   //for box       

    echo "\r\n\t\t".'<h3>SOFTWARE</h3>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t".'<div>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'<table>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."ASSET CODE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="assetCode" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."TYPE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="assetType" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."ASSET NAME";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="assetName" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."SERIAL NUMBER";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="serialNumber" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."YEAR OF PURCHASE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="yearOfPurchase" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."CAPITALIZATION DATE";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="capitalizationDate" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."LOCATION";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="location" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'."CUSTODIAN NAME";
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'<td>'.'<input type="text" id="custodianName" value="'." ".'" />';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</td>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t\t".'</tr>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t\t".'</table>';
    echo "\r\n\t\t".'</div>';   //for box   

    echo "\r\n\t".'</div>';     //for accordion
    echo "\r\n\t".'<a target="_blank" href="updateform.php?id='.$id.'"><input type="submit" value="UPDATE">'.'</a>';
    echo "\r\n".'</div>';       //for popup
}
```

Comment: post some code you tried.

Comment: Ayt, let me edit my original post.

Comment: Please post your code as this is the forum to help you if you stuck somewhere. Nobody will be able to write full code for you.

Comment: So there, what I'm actually trying to do is create an accordion box inside a pop-up for every asset with a 'wsId' that is selected. Thought the entire code was so long that's why I didn't bother posting it.

Comment: Guess I'll have to study mysqli now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I got this from somewhere from one of my old codes and kinda added on in.

```
$mysqli_connect = mysqli_connect("hostname", "user", "password")
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, "SELECT * FROM `somesection`.`sometable`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 if(fnmatch("ws-*", $row['wsld'])){
  echo "somecode";
 }
}
```

Comment: Ayt. Thanks. Ima try this one.

Comment: Used fnmatch instead of congruent operator.

Answer (score 0):

create counter and merge id with conter .

output will be like this

- wsId-1
- wsId-2
- wsId-3

or get it class no id